# NSDateFormatter stringFromDate returns nil when using 12-hour time format

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, nsdateformatter

The following code is working for 24-hour time format.

```objective-c
+ (NSString *)formatDate:(NSDate *)date useLongStyle:(BOOL)useLongStyle showDate:(BOOL)showDate showTime:(BOOL)showTime
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];

    dateFormatter.dateStyle = (useLongStyle) ? NSDateFormatterLongStyle : NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = (showDate) ? dateFormatter.dateStyle : NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = (showTime) ? NSDateFormatterShortStyle : NSDateFormatterNoStyle;

    return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
}
```

But when there are 12-hour format in the phone settings, it returns `nil`. Until I explicitly set region to e.g. Australia.

Time in `date` is in 24-hour format. Current locale is `ru_RU` (but in the `en_EN` it's the same).

Comment: Are you using an internet-style date? There's a known bug: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1480.html

Comment: @wquist Did you mean that format: `2010-11-29 09:00:00 PM +0000`?

Comment: No, that format should work... Did you try setting the date format like: `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];`

Comment: By "phone settings" I presume you mean the 12/24 option under "Settings".  iOS is "Broken as Designed" with regard to this feature -- setting it in conflict with the phone's locale causes several problems with time formatting (though this is the first time I'd heard of this particular "feechure").

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Time in `date` is in 24-hour format". NSDate is just a wrapper for a timestamp; it has no inherent format. FWIW, I tried the above code in en_US (12-hour setting) and it worked fine.

Comment: Are you sure that the passed-in `date` isn't nil?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    [formatter setLocale:locale];
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and found two solutions. One is to set the locale manually(i chose en_GB for 24 hour format) and the other is to set the timezone. Both worked individually for me. If you are not planning on dealing with dates that need to change according to time zones i suggest you go for setting locale because when dealing with timezones, the source and destination timezones comes into play and you need not deal with all that unless absolutely necessary. So try setting the locale, else go for timezone. Somehow, it helped override the system settings.

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
```